# Behaviour of externalizable interface when write external has more properties than read external

Tags: java, serialization, externalizable

I am exploring on externalizable interface. I found a strange behaviour when I wrote more property in serialized file than what I read. Below is my employee class.

```
public class Employee implements Externalizable {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Boolean isTempEmp;      

    public Employee(int id, String name, Boolean isTempEmp) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.isTempEmp = isTempEmp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", isTempEmp=" + isTempEmp + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {

        out.writeInt(id);
        out.writeUTF(name);
        out.writeBoolean(isTempEmp);
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        this.id=in.readInt();
        this.name=in.readUTF();
        //this.isTempEmp=in.readBoolean();
    }

}
```

And Below is my class for externalizing employee object in file and read from the file

```
public class ExternalizeTest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee emp1=new Employee(1, "Swet", true);
        Employee emp4=new Employee(2, "Varun", true);
        try(OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream("Employee.txt");
                ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(os);) {

            emp1.writeExternal(oos);
            emp4.writeExternal(oos);


        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Employee emp2=new Employee(3, "Test1", false);
        Employee emp3=new Employee(4, "Test2", false);
        try(InputStream is=new FileInputStream("Employee.txt");
                ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(is);) {
            emp2.readExternal(ois);
            emp3.readExternal(ois);


        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        System.out.println("After externalization: \n"+emp2.toString());
        System.out.println(emp3.toString());
    }

}
```

Below is the output I am getting:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFChar(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at serialization.externalize.Employee.readExternal(Employee.java:40)
    at serialization.externalize.ExternalizeTest2.main(ExternalizeTest2.java:32)


    After externalization: 
    Employee [id=1, name=Swet, isTempEmp=false]
    Employee [id=16777216, name=Test2, isTempEmp=false]
```

Not sure how id assigned to emp3 is 16777216.

Answer (score 0):

```
emp1.writeExternal(oos);
emp4.writeExternal(oos);
```

You're doing it wrong. This should be:

```
oos.writeObject(emp1);
oos.writeObject(emp4);
```

Similarly

```
emp2.readExternal(ois);
emp3.readExternal(ois);
```

should be

```
emp2 = (Employee)ois.readObject();
emp3 = (Employee)ois.readObject();
```

The way you have it, you're just calling your own, wrong, methods: not doing Serialization at all.